# Android How to put Battery information?

Tags: java, android, battery

How to display the batterylevel of the phone in android as a textview ?

Answer (score 1):

Before asking any question please do use Google .By The Way Click [Here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/05/android-battery-percentage-example.html#.UybRjnWSzeU)
I hope it helps you .

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to display the current battery level as a percentage, it's not necessary to register a receiver and so on. This will do it:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = getActivity().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

The battery level of my device is currently 94% - batteryPct has a value of 0.94.

This could then be displayed in a TextView like this:

```
textView.setText(Float.toString(batteryPct * 100) + "%"); // Displays '94.0%' using my example value
```

See: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have tutorials Check  [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html). In particular:

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a broadcast receiver, as this will fire the onRecieve every time the state of the battery changes, so as the charge drops your values will always be accurate.

In your activity's onCreate you need to register a broadcast receiver for the battery state:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);


    batteryMonitor = new batteryChargeMonitor();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(batteryMonitor, filter);
```

The batteryMonitor class looks like this:

```
private class batteryChargeMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

        if(status > -1 && scale > -1 && level > -1)
        {           

                   float charge = (level/(float)scale) * 1oo; 
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Battery Charge: " + charge + "%" Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING
                            || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from link here [link](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)
 receiver

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml add below

code changes

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
  Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
// Are we charging / charged?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                 status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
```

// How are we charging?

```
int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```